# Jetty and tomcat are responding on the browser but giving a connection refused error via cURL

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, curl, jetty

I'm getting a weird problem on a local solr-jetty installation on a Ubuntu machine. I just did a  "sudo apt-get install solr-jetty" (which installs jetty as a dependency).

When I open `http://127.0.0.1:8080` on my browser, I get the "welcome to jetty 6 on debian" page. When I try to:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

I get an html informing me of `(111) Connection refused` response. Does anyone have any idea about what's happening?

Thanks.

---

Edit:

Apparently the problem is not jetty. I removed jetty and tried tomcat6 with and the same problem is still happening. Maybe some network config on this particular machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if you've got any environment variable like "http_proxy" set in your shell:

```
env | grep -i proxy
```

If that's the case, try disabling it looking for it being set up in `/etc/profile.d/` or `/etc/env.d` or `$HOME/.bashrc`. YMMV because I have no idea where ubuntu puts its stuff.

If you need the proxy for other stuff, you can add an exception as in https://serverfault.com/questions/42426/proxy-exceptions-when-using-http-proxy-env-var :

```
export  no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8 #etc.
```

Comment: Oh hell... yep. I'm under a proxy. What should I do? If I unset the proxy variables, everything else will stop working. :/

Comment: Here: http://serverfault.com/questions/42426/proxy-exceptions-when-using-http-proxy-env-var

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect the new comments.